# wi-fi on Pi 4 will not connect to iPhone hotspot

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-4

My rpi4 will not connect to my iPhone 8 hotspot. I does connect to the hotspot from my iPad mini. Additionally, the rpi4 doesn't connect automaticslly on startup after successfully connecting during a previous session. Every time I restart the rpi4 I have to manually fiddle with wi-fi connectivity settings, on the iPad and the rpi4, until it finally connects.

Any ideas on how to resolve these issues?

Comment: Can you please share /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf ?

Comment: I'll post the contents of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` in a couple of hours

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer an issue. I experienced so many problems with my Pi-4 that I decided to nuke and pave the whole installation. The device did not always boot properly. I had difficulty connecting bluetooth devices as well as connecting to wi-fi networks. It all seems much better now.